# 3 buttons to draw 3 different objects in a jPanel

Tags: java, swing

i have a simple question but for some reason I'm stuck and cant figure it out.
I have a simple code with 3 buttons in a JPanel each one of the buttons should draw at the JPanel with the overriden PaintComponent and it does but What i want to do is make the shapes stay.
(after i will change it to random positions )
any help would be apreciated thank you!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ex3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton circle, triang, square;
    JPanel jp, jButton;
    boolean drawSq, drawCir, drawTr;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new Ex3();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Ex3()
    {
        super("Ex3");
        setSize(400, 500);

        circle = new JButton("Circle");
        triang = new JButton("Triangle");
        square = new JButton("Square");
        drawCir = false;
        drawSq = false;
        drawTr = false;
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 30));

        jButton = new JPanel();
        jp = new CustomPanel();

        circle.addActionListener(this);
        triang.addActionListener(this);
        square.addActionListener(this);

        jButton.add(circle);
        jButton.add(triang);
        jButton.add(square);
        jButton.add(new JLabel("Kayy"));

        jp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == circle)
        {
            drawCir = true;
            System.out.println("created cricle");

        }
        if(e.getSource() == triang)
        {
            drawTr = true;
            System.out.println("created triangle");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == square)
        {
            drawSq = true;
            System.out.println("created square");
        }
        repaint();
    }

    class CustomPanel extends JPanel
    {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(drawSq)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawRect(((int)Math.random()* 20), 50, 200, 150);
                drawSq = false;
            }
            else if(drawTr)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }
            else if(drawCir)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawOval(182, 124, 200, 200);
            }
            else
            {
            }
            //drawSq = false;
            drawTr = false;
            drawCir = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are not even drawing three shapes - so what do you want??

Comment: i dont want to use shapes, just so that the drawRect or drawOval stays when another button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i want to do is make the shapes stay

Then you need to repaint the shapes every time the component is repainted.

There are two common approaches to do this:

1. paint to a BufferedImage
2. keep a list of Object to paint and iterate through the list to paint each object

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of each approach. Which approach you use will depend on your exact requirements.

Also, you should never change the state of your component in the painting method. You can't control when the paintComponent() method is invoked. Sometimes the system will repaint a component. So the presence of your Boolean variables indicates a design problem.